# Assign several variable names at once

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, collections

I'm working in python, and I've got a list, labelled `arr`, let's say containing 10 elements.

How would I quickly go about assigning the first 10 letters of the alphabet as variable names for these 10 elements?

That is,

```
a=arr[0]
b=arr[1]

.
.
.

j=arr[9]
```

Comment: first of it won't happen "at once". second I suggest You use either a dictionary or You could try writing to the file itself, or just do what @OlvinRoght said which is WAY easier tho it has to be done somewhat manually

Comment: In general, _don't_. Use `arr[0]`, not `a`. Dynamically injecting names into your namespace will break a lot of code-quality-analysis tools and IDE autocompletion, and will make other people trying to read your codebase very unhappy..

Comment: @Matiiss How would I use a dictionary to make this process (for me, not the computer) quicker? I understand how to make the associations, my issue is just the tedium. OlvinRoght's solution seems simplest though I thought there might be a sleeker way to do this, especially if I've got even more variable names I want to assign

Comment: @Mike, generally if you have values already in the list, just access to those values using indexes, do not copy them to separate variables.

Comment: I would say that @BuddyBob 's answer is the best in this case

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = arr
```

if `arr` has as many elements as you're assigning. Otherwise you'll have to slice `arr` to the correct length:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = arr[:10]
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to be the simplest method

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dict

```
import string
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var = {let:num for num,let in zip(arr,string.ascii_lowercase)}
```

Then access variables like

```
print(var['a'])
```

Comment: Usually it happens when you answer question which is duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how many values of it you are assigning, if you are assigning every value in it to a variable, you can do this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = arr
```

Otherwise you'll have to specify which parts:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = arr[first:last]
```